# Is Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Grouped ever used?

Tags: checkout, php, grouped-products

There's a cart rendered for grouped products in Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Grouped, but it doesn't appear to ever be used.  Am I wrong on this one?  Anyone got the back story here?

---

Edit:
@oleksii.svarychevskyi pointed out that the block appears in the layout XML files.  Still, I have the question - since grouped products are added to cart as their individual simple components, and not presented as members of a grouped product, is this block ever used?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in checkout.xml

```
<block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
    .....
    <action method="addItemRender">
        <type>grouped</type>
        <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block>
        <template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template>
    </action>
    .....
</block>
```

it means that it is used for rendering grouped product information in cart.

It is only one example, but it is used in many places where magento needs to display grouped product information.

Comment: Ah! I was only searching in app/code, not templates. Well done!

Comment: I think the question still stands.  See the edit above.

Comment: Just change some code inside `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` and see output.

Comment: The template is used, but I don't see that the block is.  It's just simple products by the time they get to cart.

Comment: run `var_dump(get_class($this))` inside template and you will see to which block it is assigned

Comment: It's all Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer - looks like the grouped item is pretty well forgotten by the time we get to the quote/cart stage.